# GWT Material DatePicker auto open on tab change

Tags: gwt, datepicker, gwt-material-design

I found a strange bug in GWT Material DatePicker, it works on officiat GWT website too:

If you go here - https://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/#pickers
, try to pick some date, close DatePicker and open a new tab in your browser and go back, DatePicker will be opened. So, how can i fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you want to join https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt for you GWT questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it's a bug. Hope they'll fix it someday.